# How to stop a screen process in linux?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I am running a script on a remote server. I ran the script in `screen`, however I need to stop it before it completes since I need to update the script. I can easily detach from `screen`, however, is there a way to kill a `screen` process?

Comment: Do you really want to kill `screen(1)`? Or would you rather kill the process you started inside `screen(1)`?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: I would like to kill the process that I started in `screen`.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

CTRL+a and then 'k' will kill a screen session.

Comment: Thank you! I just added a Terminal Hotkey that goes "\001ky" (Ctrl-A, k and y for "yes"). On a far note, I have a hotkey bound to the "Home" key that goes "cd ~/ Enter"  There’s no place like cd ~/

Answer (score 75):

There are a couple of 'screen' ways to kill a specific screen session from the command line (non-interactively).

1) send a 'quit' command:

```
screen -X -S "sessionname" quit
```

2) send a Ctrl-C to a screen session running a script:

```
screen -X -S "sessionname" stuff "^C"
```

In both cases, you would need to use 'screen -ls' to find the session name of the screen session you want to kill ... if there is only one screen session running, you won't need to specify the -S "sessionname" parameter.

Answer (score 9):

I used this to quit hundreds of erroneous screen sessions created by a buggy command:

`for s in $(screen -ls|grep -o -P "1\d+.tty"); do screen -X -S $s quit; done;`

where: the `grep -o -P "1\d+.tty"` is the command to get session names with Perl-like name regex `"1\d+.tty"` which captures all sessions start with number `1`, has some other numbers (`\d`) and end with `.tty`

**Warning**:
You should test with this command first to see you get the exact list of sessions you want before apply the above command. This is to avoid quitting unwanted sessions:

`for s in $(screen -ls|grep -o -P "1\d+.tty"); do echo $s; done;`

I always to this `echo` test whenever the list in `for` loop is not clear, for example, the one generated by sub-command in `$()` expansion.

Answer (score 5):

previous answers didn't work for me on a winputty terminal and amazon ssh server connection.. but this one does work:

```
screen -S yourscreentitlehere -X stuff $'\003'
```

references:

- [Sending ctrl-c to specific screen session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001578/sending-ctrl-c-to-specific-screen-session/16006504#16006504)
- $'\003' is ctrl+c http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html
- stuff is https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Paste

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for! None of the other solutions would stop the screen session if it was currently running an active process.

Answer (score 2):

I am using putty, and it seems I am already in the screen and couldn't open and close. Every time I do "exit", I just close the putty window. Here is the termimal print

`>>screen -r`

```
    21063.unlimited (11/08/20 15:45:19)     (Attached)
    24054.cure6     (11/08/20 09:46:13)     (Attached)
```

`There is no screen to be resumed.`
and

`screen -S 21063.unlimited -X stuff $'\003'`

does not do anything.
I found that as simple as the following line works perfect

`screen -x 21063.unlimited`

it sends me back into the screen and from there "exit" works.
Note that it is lower-case `-x`