# Sending ctrl-c to specific screen session

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, sigint

I am designing a script to launch a process inside a named screen session.

```
as_user "screen -p 0 -S **$command** -X eval 'stuff \"wine LFS.exe /cfg=**$command**.cfg\"\015'"
```

So `bash myscript.sh start test` will create a screen named test and run the `test.cfg` with the software.

Now I want my script to access the specific screen session and do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the running process so i can kill the screen session.

Something like this:

```
as_user "screen -p 0 -S **$command** **... kill the process with ctrl-c...**"
as_user "screen -p 0 -S **$command** -X eval 'stuff \"exit\"\015'"
```

Answer (score 27):

I don't quite understand you but to send `ctrl-c` to a *window* in a screen session:

```
screen -S session_name -X at window_number stuff $'\003'
# or
screen -S session_name -X -p window_number stuff $'\003'
```

If you want to send something to *all* the windows, use `#` (needs to be quoted) as the *window_number*.

**UPDATE:**

Screen's `stuff` command also supports `^X` (or `^x`) to mean `CTRL-X` so the following command can also be used to send `CTRL-C`.

```
# Here '^C' is two chars, '^' and 'C'
screen -S session_name -X at window_number stuff '^C'
```

Comment: Could not get `at` to work, but this worked for me for the active window only, which might be useful for someone: `screen -S session_name -X stuff $'\003'`

Comment: `screen -S session_name -X at "#" stuff $'\003'` with `screen -S session_name -X quit` works perfect for me. I am able to kill any screen session now. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for! Do you have more information the `$'\003'` encoding? Can I assume Ctrl+A would be `001`, Ctrl+B would be `002` etc? Also, is there a way to send cursor up, down, left, and right keys?

Comment: for ctrl chars see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards

Comment: Oh and now that I'm wondering, since you mentioned screen also supports `^C`. How do I type a literal `^` character?

Comment: in the answer, for `^C`, the `^` is the *caret* char. it's not the *control* char.

Comment: to send cursor up/down/left/right, you can first get the control sequence with `tput`. e.g. to get cursor up you can `tput cuu1`. details can be found in [terminfo(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html).

Comment: Thanks! `screen -S session_name -X at window_number stuff '^C'` works great on CentOS 7.