# Can't send CTRL-C to a program in a SCREEN session from an initscript

Tags: linux, bash, init, gnu-screen

I am trying to create a CentOS initscript to wrap starting and stopping a daemon.

The daemon is a Python console application designed to run in a SCREEN session, under a specific user, and to shutdown cleanly when it detects a CTRL-C.

the initscript needs to be run as root, so I followed the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001578/sending-ctrl-c-to-specific-screen-session) and wrote this into the "stop" function:

```
su - -c "screen -S $prog -X stuff $'\003'" $screenuser
```

But it fails to stop the daemon, however if I attach to the session with

```
su - -c "screen -r $prog" $screenuser
```

and hit CTRL-C on the keyboard, the application cleanly shuts down.
I can't figure out why the scripted method does not work.

Comment: Send `SIGINT` to the process in question.

Comment: And you send a SIGINT with `kill -INT $pid` or `pkill -INT $command`

Comment: Thanks, should I send SIGINT to the screen process, or to the one running inside it? Being the process inside forked many times, how can I isolate the father's PID?

Comment: You have to send a `SIGINT` to the foreground process group of the terminal. This has been covered in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149741/send-sigint-to-child-process-of-shell-simulating-ctrlc-linux; see the solution given there