# How can I kill a running node script in a screen using Ctrl+C?

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a screen where the bot is launched through "node index.js". But how can I send c cmd to bash script "CTRL+C" and run again node js.
In other screens, the node also works, you can’t touch it
I've come to this point

```
screen -S testBot -X stuff  'node index.js\n'
```

How to kill a running node script in the screen?
As I understand the PID will always be different

```
screen -S testBot -X stuff  'node index.js\n'
```

Comment: `screen -x` & `ctrl + c` is to easy? :D What you talking about about are "signals" which can be send via the `kill` command. But for that you need to know the process id.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006504/900078